# Show different image on each page load

Tags: javascript

I have this code which simply changes 4 images on each page load.

```
<HEAD>
<script language="Javascript">
function RandomizeImage()
{
var imagesarray = new Array("001.png", "002.png", "003.png", "004.png")
var randomnumber = Math.round(Math.random()*(imagesarray.length - 1))
document.images.someimage.src = imagesarray[randomnumber]
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

</HEAD>
<BODY onload="RandomizeImage()" bgcolor="#000000">

<div id="bg">
    <IMG name="someimage" src="001.png" border="0" onclick="location.href='mailto:me@xxx.com?Subject=Hello'" id="bgg">
</div>
</BODY>
```

However, on most page reloads I get image "001.png" or "002.png". Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function getRandom(min,max) 
{
    var res =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max+1 - min) + min);
    return res;
}
```

Example: If you want to return a value from (`1,2,3,4,5`) you should chose min `1` and max `5`.

```
var rImage = '00'+getRandom(1,5)+'.png';
console.log(rImage);

// output: 001.png or 002.png or 003.png or 004.png or 005.png
```

**Edited**

Hope to help

Comment: Hey, this one seems to be the best solution. It works. Thanks

Comment: `getRandom(1,5)` will never return `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.floor()` instead of `.round()` and don't subtract 1 from the length:

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesarray.length);
```

**Edit:**  `Math.random() * 3` will give us numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 3 (exclusive). Using `Math.round()` the values that result in each number:

```
0: 0.0 — 0.4999
1: 0.5 — 1.4999
2: 1.5 — 2.4999
3: 2.5 — 2.9999
```

You can see that the high and low numbers each of half the probability of being selected as the numbers in the middle.  This is because you will never get numbers in the range `-0.5 — -0.9999` or `3.0 — 3.4999` giving these end numbers half the likelihood of being selected.

`Math.floor()` eliminates this problem because all the numbers fall within the range.  `Math.random() * 4` will give us numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 4 (exclusive). Using `Math.floor()` the values that result in each number:

```
0: 0.0 — 0.9999
1: 1.0 — 1.9999
2: 2.0 — 2.9999
3: 3.0 — 3.9999
```

You may find it useful to use a utility function such as this one:

```
function randomInt(max, min) {
    min = min || 0;
    var Max = Math.max(max, min) + 1;
    var Min = Math.min(max, min);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min)) + Min;
}
```

The nice thing about this function is that the order of the arguments doesn't matter, and `min` is optional.  Note that, since `max` is inclusive in this function, you would want to subtract 1 from the array length:

```
var randomnumber = randomInt(imagesarray.length - 1);
```

Comment: I will try this asap. Can you tell me why, in the meantime?

Comment: If I don't subtract 1, then I get empty image saying `undefine`

Comment: @sandalone - I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: I was just about to post this answer. +1.

Comment: @sandalone - If you don't subtract 1 but you continue to use `Math.round()` you will get that error.  Did you also switch to `Math.floor()`?

Comment: YEs, just like you said `var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesarray.length);`. But I solved the issue with the help of another user. Thanks and I upvoted you.

Answer (score 1):

Math.round has this effect:

```
0   <= x < 0.5   => 0
0.5 <= x < 1.5   => 1
1.5 <= x < 2.5   => 2
..
(n-0.5) <= x < n => n
```

as you can see  the first and last number has less probability to be fetched.

So a better approach is to use `Math.floor` as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)